# Remove action not working in theme

Tags: themes

i am building a custom theme and i now have to remove entry footer from it.
I am trying to get this using custom hook i made.
the code i am using to remove it is

```
add_action('after_entry_content', 'the_categories_links_removal');
function the_categories_links_removal() {
    remove_action('openblogger_entry_footer', 'openblogger_entry_footer');
}
```

but it doesn't work. Any suggestion.

Comment: you've to check how `openblogger_entry_footer` has been added via add_action() and use the same hook with an higher priority, so for example if openblogger_entry_footer has been added via `add_action('custom_action_hook','openblogger_entry_footer',10);` you've to do `remove_action('custom_action_hook','openblogger_entry_footer',11)`. Also if you use `after_entry_content` to customize your content, you must check that this hook is later than the one on which add_action() has been called, otherwise you're trying to remove something that has not yet being added

Comment: i have file named as shortcodes, that file is doing everything. I figured it out thanks for answering @AndreaSomovigo

Comment: i have another question, if you don't mind will i ask

Comment: yes ask........

Comment: @RaashidDin, when you have another question, then you have to create the new question. Comments have different purpose.

Comment: please refer to this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51788251/shortcodes-are-showing-everywhere-on-single-pages